# Trying to get colors from image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Vibrant.js to get colors from a image, I added vibrant.min.js to my files and tried to use it like:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://f1.bcbits.com/img/a1312167393_16.jpg";

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
            console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex())
});
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
    at t.getImageData (file:///C:/Users/liweda/Downloads/test/js/vibrant.min.js:1:11198)
    at new i (file:///C:/Users/liweda/Downloads/test/js/vibrant.min.js:1:6082)
    at Image.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/liweda/Downloads/test/js/functions.js:11:19)
```

How could I fix this error or are there any alternative options? I need a dominant color and less brighter color

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're loading an image asset from a 3rd party domain in relation to the domain the javascript code is running from.

For example, if you are running this locally at `http://localhost:8080` but its loading the image resource from `http://f1.bcbits.com`, then the canvas is considered tainted and you can no longer get or manipulate image data from it.

This is a security practice found in all browsers.

If your production website is `http://f1.bcbits.com`, then the code will work fine. But in order for you to develop this locally, the image you're working with needs to be loaded from the same domain as you're developing in, like `localhost`.

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot to mention the way to fix this both locally and in production. If you enable the correct CORS headers, the 3rd party domain issue goes away. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: So I tried: `img.src = "placeholder.jpg";`  but this also does not seem to work

Comment: Right, sorry I forgot to mention that your server also needs to send the correct CORS headers. I'll update the answer